# Validation to get null values

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a validation where if there is no value on a label the application will run normally. To explain better I will show you the the code that I am using and then explain it

```
Private Sub ShowTotalResult()
    SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "...."
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT 
                CAST(SUM(CAST(Filesize as float)) / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
                FROM infofile"
        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        If lblResultadoTotal.Text <> "" Then
            If SqlDR.Read() Then
                lblResultadoTotal.Text = SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

What this piece of code does is giving me the total in MB of what I got on the database. To make some tests I deleted all the info from database and when I've tried to run the application it gives me error on this line `lblResultadoTotal.Text = SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)` because there is no value on that label. So to turn that around what could I do?

I've tried to use an `If lblResultadoTotal.Text <> "" Then 
lblResultadoTotal.Text = SqlDR.GetValue(0)
End If`

This is the query that I am using to get the values from database

```
SELECT 
CAST(SUM(CAST(Filesize as float)) / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM infofile
```

This is the error `Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.`
but this does not work. Do you have any solution?

Comment: It does not affect if the label had a text or not before. If its not working is probably because of the `SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)`.  Try to store what it returns to a variable (`Dim a = SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)`) and then `lblResultadoTotal.Text=a` to see where it crashes

Comment: It crashes here: lblResultadoTotal.Text = SqlDR.GetDecimal(0) because this data have a null value @Aimnox

Comment: But it's mostly sure a problem with the `SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)` and not the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call GetDecimal if the field is NULL because internally the GetDecimal method tries to cast the null value to a decimal. You can read the warning in the Remarks section of the [GetDecimal page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN

It is easy to fix using [SqlDataReader.IsDbNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
' A call to SqlDataReader.Read is always required to position '
' the reader on the first record returned by your query'
if SqlDR.Read() then 
    if SqlDR.IsDbNull(0) Then

        lblResultadoTotal.Text = "0,00"
    else 
        lblResultadoTotal.Text = SqlDR.GetDecimal(0)

    End If
End If
```

However, I am a bit perplexed from all those casts inside your query. I would get the raw value and try to convert the values obtained in VB.NET code where it will be more easy to do it. (Need to test for performances)

Comment: I am trying to get the same values from the database, for example there, I got 13.06 and I want it to return 13.06 and not 13 you know what I mean? Btw that code does not work

Comment: I've just edited the post with the query that I am using

Comment: What is the datatype of the column FileSize? What do you mean with _that code doesn't work_?

Comment: By the way, remove as soon as possible that Exit Sub inside the If test. This way you don't close the connection worse you don't dispose it

Comment: I forget about remove it

Comment: The data type is int

Comment: And it represents the size in bytes of the file?

Comment: Your code gives me this error "invalid attempt to read when no data is present"

Comment: It keep giving me that error because of this line: If SqlDR.IsDBNull(0) Then

Comment: I've just found out the error. I will edit your post to makes this better

Comment: Yes. I was not able to edit your post... Just change from "0" to "0,00". And it actually works ahahah

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not IsDBNull(SqlDR) Then
    lblResultadoTotal.Text = SqlDR.GetValue(0)
End If
```

Maybe, the actual error message would help

Comment: Where should I put it? Inside of what?

Comment: Just have a check for `DBNull` before you assign `lblResultadoTotal` with the value from the database. Can you post the exact error you were getting? Steve's answer might be better